# Inconsistency in returning primitive arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, return

The following show different ways of instantiating and returning a primitive array. However, for some reason, the last one doesn't work. Is there a valid explanation for this inconsistency? Why doesn't the last block work?

Block 1

```
    int[] a = new int[] {50};
    return a;    // works fine
```

Block 2

```
    int[] a = {50};
    return a;    // works fine
```

Block 3

```
    return new int[] {50};    // works fine
```

Block 4

```
    return {50};   // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why doesn't the last block work?

Because an array initializer ([JLS 10.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)) is only valid in either a variable declaration, as per your first and second blocks, or as part of an array creation expression ([JLS 15.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1)), as per your third block.

Your fourth block isn't either a variable declaration or an array creation expression, so it's not valid.

Note that this isn't specific to primitive arrays at all - it's the same for *all* arrays.

Comment: Great, thanks for this! I don't really see how it applies as you can't really omit the `new` in `List<Integer> = new ArrayList<>();`?

Comment: @Calculus5000: Well that's not for arrays, is it? Basically the syntax for arrays isn't exactly the same as the syntax for other things.

Comment: Oh ok. So it only works for primitive arrays then? Because I got confused by `Note that this isn't specific to primitive arrays at all - it's the same for all arrays.` In Java, I understand that arrays and primitive arrays are synonymous, right?

Comment: @Calculus5000: No, not at all. For example: `String[] x = { "foo", "bar" };`. `String` isn't a primitive type.